# Machine Learning: Which is algorithm I'm looking for?

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, data-processing

Let's say I'm scraping a website of apples, and all of them have different prices, and different properties. The example data extracted could be:

```
Apple 1 -> color: red, days_old: 15, flavour: sweet -> 10$
Apple 2 -> color: green -> 3$
Apple 3 -> flavour: sweet -> 5$
Apple 4 -> color: red, days_old: 10 -> 15$
```

So in this dataset example I have 4 different apples, which have different properties (not only values, but different number of properties), and I would like to know how each property and value affects the final price of the apple. For example: color is red -> +5$, flavour is sweet -> +3$, more than 10 days_old -> -2$...

Which will be the algorithm that I'm looking for?

Comment: If you could extract all these properties and use a regression model, you can directly predict the expected apples' price. Generally, pricing is not simply calculated based on adding or subtracting from a base price.

Comment: @EmberXu Thanks for the answer. Yes, I would be able to predict the price in that way, but I also would like to go further and understand how do the different properties of the apple affect this prediction, and assess the price of an apple

Comment: You could use [feature selection algorithms](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_selection.html) to select the most useful features; or you could do a two-step regression, for instance if I ask you the price of a new apple, first you find a few apples similar to mine whose price you already know, using [nearest neighbour](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/neighbors.html) or maybe [decision trees](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/tree.html), and then you do a simple [linear regression](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/linear_model.html) on this subset of apples.

Comment: Although the most important feature for the price of an apple might be its weight, and that's notably missing from your dataset :p

Comment: Also note that it's easier to build a good regression model if you have some specific domain knowledge, i.e. some personal prior idea about how important the features can be. If you hoping for your model to "understand" apples from scratch, that's possible too, but will probably require **a lot** more data to get good results.

Comment: @Stef hahaha yes! This was the piece of the puzzle I was missing, the weight :')

Thanks for your answer, I feel like I'm getting closer to what I'm looking for.
The nearest neighbor approach looks good, even though it doesn't give me the evaluations of each property. I'll try to research a bit more

Comment: @XaviOrtega The idea of the nearest neighbour is that it's typical that the price is linear to some features... if you're in some category. For instance imagine with appartment and house prices instead of apples. The price is maybe linear in the surface of the apartment and distance from the train station... if you compare several apartments of the same type in the same area. But an apartment is going to have a very different price than a house, and an apartment inside the city will have a different price than apartment in the suburbs, etc.

Comment: @Stef in my regression model, all variables are important because they all influence on the final price of the product, I'm just trying to automate the possibility of understanding how that different values of properties actually affect the price, and then be able to evaluate the price of a new product outside the dataset

Comment: So you use nearest neighbour or decision tree or some other [clustering](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html#clustering) algorithm, first; and then you do a simple linear regression inside the subgroups

Comment: Yes, but even if all features are important, the relationship might not be a simple mathematical formula if you look at your whole dataset; but it might be a simple mathematical formula if you only look at some subset. So first you cut your dataset into subsets, then you try to identify the formula inside each subset

Comment: Thanks, @Stef, I think that I got it now! Very useful information here!